# Supervisor is acting weird

Tags: phd, interpersonal-issues

I am female and married. My PhD supervisor told me that I am lovely and he likes me. He asked me to go for a special date. I rejected as I am married though my husband is in my home country, not with me here. During Christmas, he told me to inform him when I roam around the city. Despite of having his family and guests in his house, he told me that he was available to roam around with me. I  also rejected him that time. He also tries to get closer to me violating my personal space and he told me to be closer to him. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Can you change supervisors?

Comment: @Buffy- Unfortunately no.

Comment: You go to the university ombuds, the department chair, and the dean. This behavior is unacceptable, not weird.

Comment: @GoodDeeds- Yes, pretty much. Thanks.